# SciPy/Numpy's Pooling/Convolution faster than Tensorflow's Convolution/Pooling?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, scipy

I am trying to use GPUs to accelerate convolution and pooling operations in my neural network application(Spiking networks). I wrote a small script to see how much speedup I can get by using Tensorflow. Surprisingly, SciPy/Numpy does better. In my application, all the inputs(images) are stored on the disk but for an example, I created a randomly initialized image of size `27x27` and weights kernel of size `5x5x30`, i made sure that I am not transferring anything from CPU to GPU and I also increased the input image size to `270x270` and the weights kernel to `7x7x30`, still I don't see any improvement. I made sure that all the TF methods are in fact being executed on my GPUs by setting

`sess =tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

I have access to 2 GPUs(Tesla K20m) on a cluster.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import time
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

image_size = 27
kernel_size = 5
nofMaps = 30

def convolution(Image, weights):
    in_channels = 1 # 1 because our image has 1 units in the -z direction. 
    out_channels = weights.shape[-1]
    strides_1d = [1, 1, 1, 1]

    #in_2d = tf.constant(Image, dtype=tf.float32)
    in_2d = Image
    #filter_3d = tf.constant(weights, dtype=tf.float32)
    filter_3d =weights

    in_width = int(in_2d.shape[0])
    in_height = int(in_2d.shape[1])

    filter_width = int(filter_3d.shape[0])
    filter_height = int(filter_3d.shape[1])

    input_4d   = tf.reshape(in_2d, [1, in_height, in_width, in_channels])
    kernel_4d = tf.reshape(filter_3d, [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels])
    inter = tf.nn.conv2d(input_4d, kernel_4d, strides=strides_1d, padding='VALID')
    output_3d = tf.squeeze(inter)
    output_3d= sess.run(output_3d)
    return output_3d


def pooling(Image):
    in_channels = Image.shape[-1]
    Image_3d = tf.constant(Image, dtype = tf.float32)
    in_width = int(Image.shape[0])
    in_height = int(Image.shape[1])
    Image_4d = tf.reshape(Image_3d,[1,in_width,in_height,in_channels])
    pooled_pots4d = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=Image_4d, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pooled_pots3d = tf.squeeze(pooled_pots4d)
    return sess.run(pooled_pots3d)


t1 = time.time()
#with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
Image = tf.random_uniform([image_size, image_size], name='Image')
weights = tf.random_uniform([kernel_size,kernel_size,nofMaps], name='Weights')
conv_result = convolution(Image,weights)
pool_result = pooling(conv_result)

print('Time taken:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
#with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'):
print('Pool_result shape:{}'.format(pool_result.shape))
#print('first map of pool result:\n',pool_result[:,:,0])


def scipy_convolution(Image,weights):
    instant_conv1_pots = np.zeros((image_size-kernel_size+1,image_size-kernel_size+1,nofMaps))
    for i in range(weights.shape[-1]):
        instant_conv1_pots[:,:,i]=signal.correlate(Image,weights[:,:,i],mode='valid',method='fft')
    return instant_conv1_pots

def scipy_pooling(conv1_spikes):
    '''
       Reshape splitting each of the two axes into two each such that the
       latter of the split axes is of the same length as the block size.
       This would give us a 4D array. Then, perform maximum finding along those
       latter axes, which would be the second and fourth axes in that 4D array.
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813722/numpy-array-reshaped-but-how-to-change-axis-for-pooling
    '''
    if(conv1_spikes.shape[0]%2!=0): #if array is odd size then omit the last row and col
        conv1_spikes = conv1_spikes[0:-1,0:-1,:]
    else:
        conv1_spikes = conv1_spikes
    m,n = conv1_spikes[:,:,0].shape
    o   = conv1_spikes.shape[-1]
    pool1_spikes = np.zeros((m/2,n/2,o))
    for i in range(o):
        pool1_spikes[:,:,i]=conv1_spikes[:,:,i].reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).max(axis=(1,3))
    return pool1_spikes
t1 = time.time()
Image = np.random.rand(image_size,image_size)
weights = np.random.rand(kernel_size,kernel_size,nofMaps)
conv_result = scipy_convolution(Image,weights)
pool_result = scipy_pooling(conv_result)
print('Time taken:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
print('Pool_result shape:{}'.format(pool_result.shape))
#print('first map of pool result:\n',pool_result[:,:,0])
~
```

Results are as follows:

```
Time taken:0.746644973755
Pool_result shape:(11, 11, 30)
Time taken:0.0127348899841
Pool_result shape:(11, 11, 30)
```

Comment: Your timing includes not just the convolution operation, but also building the graph, setting up variables etc. Since that takes quite a bit of time this is not a fair comparison.

Comment: I increased the size of input image to 270x270 and kernel to 7x7x30 still TF takes more time, Does TF take more time for setting up graphs for larger images?

Comment: I don't understand why it was down voted, I explained what I did and I also explored other options which could be potentially slowing down the code, since I didn't find any issues I came to this site asking for suggestions, if people don't want to suggest then I am not sure why this site exists!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is also nothing more for me to say. Again, your comparison is not fair since you include the time to build the graph for the TF version (which is substantial). Until you provide large-scale examples demonstrating that TF is slower than scipy in a realistic setting (e.g. batch inputs, multiple batches processed sequentially, multiple convolution layers) I don't see the point in this question.

Answer (score -1):

With suggestions from the commenter, I set `image_size=270` and enclosed both `convolution and pool` functions in a for loop, now, `TF` performs better than `SciPy` note that I am using `tf.nn.conv2d` and NOT the `tf.layers.conv2d`. I also set the parameter `use_cudnn_on_gpu=True` in `tf.nn.conv2d` but that didn't hurt or help.

Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import time
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

image_size = 270
kernel_size = 5
nofMaps = 30

def convolution(Image, weights):
    in_channels = 1 # 1 because our image has 1 units in the -z direction. 
    out_channels = weights.shape[-1]
    strides_1d = [1, 1, 1, 1]

    #in_2d = tf.constant(Image, dtype=tf.float32)
    in_2d = Image
    #filter_3d = tf.constant(weights, dtype=tf.float32)
    filter_3d =weights

    in_width = int(in_2d.shape[0])
    in_height = int(in_2d.shape[1])

    filter_width = int(filter_3d.shape[0])
    filter_height = int(filter_3d.shape[1])

    input_4d   = tf.reshape(in_2d, [1, in_height, in_width, in_channels])
    kernel_4d = tf.reshape(filter_3d, [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels])
    inter = tf.nn.conv2d(input_4d, kernel_4d, strides=strides_1d, padding='VALID',use_cudnn_on_gpu=True)
    output_3d = tf.squeeze(inter)
    #t1 = time.time()
    output_3d= sess.run(output_3d)
    #print('TF Time for Conv:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
    return output_3d


def pooling(Image):
    in_channels = Image.shape[-1]
    Image_3d = tf.constant(Image, dtype = tf.float32)
    in_width = int(Image.shape[0])
    in_height = int(Image.shape[1])
    Image_4d = tf.reshape(Image_3d,[1,in_width,in_height,in_channels])
    pooled_pots4d = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=Image_4d, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pooled_pots3d = tf.squeeze(pooled_pots4d)
    #t1 = time.time()
    pool_res = sess.run(pooled_pots3d)
    #print('TF Time for Pool:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
    return pool_res


#with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
Image = tf.random_uniform([image_size, image_size], name='Image')
weights = tf.random_uniform([kernel_size,kernel_size,nofMaps], name='Weights')
#init = tf.global_variables_initializer
#sess.run(init)
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(150):
    #t1 = time.time()
    conv_result = convolution(Image,weights)
    pool_result = pooling(conv_result)
    #print('TF Time taken:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
print('TF Time taken:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
#with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'):
print('TF Pool_result shape:{}'.format(pool_result.shape))
#print('first map of pool result:\n',pool_result[:,:,0])


def scipy_convolution(Image,weights):
    instant_conv1_pots = np.zeros((image_size-kernel_size+1,image_size-kernel_size+1,nofMaps))
    for i in range(weights.shape[-1]):
        instant_conv1_pots[:,:,i]=signal.correlate(Image,weights[:,:,i],mode='valid',method='fft')
    return instant_conv1_pots

def scipy_pooling(conv1_spikes):
    '''
       Reshape splitting each of the two axes into two each such that the
       latter of the split axes is of the same length as the block size.
       This would give us a 4D array. Then, perform maximum finding along those
       latter axes, which would be the second and fourth axes in that 4D array.
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813722/numpy-array-reshaped-but-how-to-change-axis-for-pooling
    '''
    if(conv1_spikes.shape[0]%2!=0): #if array is odd size then omit the last row and col
        conv1_spikes = conv1_spikes[0:-1,0:-1,:]
    else:
        conv1_spikes = conv1_spikes
    m,n = conv1_spikes[:,:,0].shape
    o   = conv1_spikes.shape[-1]
    pool1_spikes = np.zeros((m/2,n/2,o))
    for i in range(o):
        pool1_spikes[:,:,i]=conv1_spikes[:,:,i].reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).max(axis=(1,3))
    return pool1_spikes
Image = np.random.rand(image_size,image_size)
weights = np.random.rand(kernel_size,kernel_size,nofMaps)
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(150):
    conv_result = scipy_convolution(Image,weights)
    pool_result = scipy_pooling(conv_result)
print('Scipy Time taken:{}'.format(time.time()-t1))
print('Scipy Pool_result shape:{}'.format(pool_result.shape))
#print('first map of pool result:\n',pool_result[:,:,0])
```

Here are results:

```
image_size = 27x27
kernel_size = 5x5x30
iterations = 150
TF Time taken:11.0800771713
TF Pool_result shape:(11, 11, 30)
Scipy Time taken:1.4141368866
Scipy Pool_result shape:(11, 11, 30)

image_size = 270x270
kernel_size = 5x5x30
iterations = 150

TF Time taken:26.2359631062
TF Pool_result shape:(133, 133, 30)
Scipy Time taken:31.6651778221
Scipy Pool_result shape:(11, 11, 30)


image_size = 500x500
kernel_size = 5x5x30
iterations = 150

TF Time taken:89.7967050076
TF Pool_result shape:(248, 248, 30)
Scipy Time taken:143.391746044
Scipy Pool_result shape:(248, 248, 30)
```

In the 2nd case you can see that I got about 18% reduction in time. 
In the 3rd case you can see that I goto about 38% reduction in time.